# Divide rows by more than one columns containing commas

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to separate some rows of a dataframe where commas exist.

This is an example fragment:

```
name  ref   alt    exon   impact score
ID1    A    C,T    1,2     l,h     5
ID2    T    A       6      h       8
ID3    T    G,C,A  2,5,7   l,l,h   10,2,3
ID4    C    G       3      m       2
```

How could I perform the following transformation?

```
name   ref   alt   exon   impact  score
ID1    A     C      1       l      5
ID1    A     T      2       h      5
ID2    T     A      6       h      8
ID3    T     G      2       l      10
ID3    T     C      5       l      2
ID3    T     A      7       h      3
ID4    C     G      3       m      2
```

I was trying something as:

```
df %>% 
    mutate(alt=strsplit(alt, ",")) %>% 
    unnest(alt)
```

However I do not wish to divide the rows just based on one column, but to take into account all the columns where there are more than one value (and to repeat the values where no commas exist).

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `separate_rows` from the package `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyr)

separate_rows(df, everything(), sep = ",")

# A tibble: 7 × 6
  name  ref   alt   exon  impact score
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>
1 ID1   A     C     1     l      5    
2 ID1   A     T     2     h      5    
3 ID2   T     A     6     h      8    
4 ID3   T     G     2     l      10   
5 ID3   T     C     5     l      2    
6 ID3   T     A     7     h      3    
7 ID4   C     G     3     m      2
```

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4"), ref = c("A", 
"T", "T", "C"), alt = c("C,T", "A", "G,C,A", "G"), exon = c("1,2", 
"6", "2,5,7", "3"), impact = c("l,h", "h", "l,l,h", "m"), score = c("5", 
"8", "10,2,3", "2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Nice :-) thanks! (I am learning tidyr and so was following this question)

Comment: @StewartWiseman You can also set `convert = TRUE` in `separate_rows` to transform those numeric-like columns(exon, score) into numeric if you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `splitstackshape` and `zoo`:

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(zoo)

df <- cSplit(df, 1:ncol(df), "long", sep = ",", type.convert = F)
na.locf(df[rowSums(is.na(df)) != ncol(df),])
```

**Output**

```
   name ref alt exon impact score
1:  ID1   A   C    1      l     5
2:  ID1   A   T    2      h     5
3:  ID2   T   A    6      h     8
4:  ID3   T   G    2      l    10
5:  ID3   T   C    5      l     2
6:  ID3   T   A    7      h     3
7:  ID4   C   G    3      m     2
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4"), ref = c("A", 
"T", "T", "C"), alt = c("C,T", "A", "G,C,A", "G"), exon = c("1,2", 
"6", "2,5,7", "3"), impact = c("l,h", "h", "l,l,h", "m"), score = c("5", 
"8", "10,2,3", "2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```